# How to create alert function in php?

Tags: javascript, php, function, class, alert

i want insert user in db mysql, i have a controller php, im validate if user exist in db  through a function, then if or not exist i want show alert function an redirect to php page, for that im using:

```
<?php

 if(dao::existUser($user)) {
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";
    echo "alert('user exist!');\n";
    echo "window.location = ('../insertUser.php');\n";
    echo "</script>"; 
 }
```

this function works!! but 
i want to encapsulate the function in a method to later call it

example:

```
<?php
class Utils {
  static function responseText($message, $url) {
     echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";
     echo "alert('"+$message+"');\n";
     echo "window.location = ('"+$url+"');\n";
     echo "</script>";
  }
}
```

then, in my controller:

```
<?php

 if(dao::existUser($user)) {
   Utils::responseText("user exist",'../insertUser.php');
 }
```

but not work, and after call responseText, my page  goes blank

Comment: check your concatenation Javascript's `+` instead of PHP's `.`  As in `echo "alert('"+$message+"');\n";` should be `echo "alert('".$message."');\n";`  OR just `echo "alert('$message');\n";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is wrong ( likely a quoting issue ), but I would suggest using a HEREDOC style for this and return the text not output the HTML from the class by itself.  Latter it could be hard to track where this output is coming from by looking just in the class that calls it.  By doing `echo Utills::..` you'll be able to easily see it's outputting something, whiteout having to look into what the class does.

So like this.

```
<?php
class Utils {
  static function responseText($message, $url) {
     return <<<HTML 
     <script type="text/javascript">
         alert('$message');
         window.location = '$url';
     </script>
HTML; //nothing can go here no space ( before or after ) and not even this comment, nothing but HTML; litterally
  }
}

echo Utils::responseText("user exist",'../insertUser.php');
```

HEREDOCs are a way of doing a text block without using any quotes, beware of the note i put in comments...  In this case it makes the Javascript string so much more simple when you don't have to manage quote usage.

Another suggestion for this class if it is to be a collection of static methods, you can make it where it can't be instantiated ( created using new class() )  Like this

```
<?php
class Utils {
    private function __construct(){}  //no instantion
    private function __clone(){}  //no cloning
```

This way you don't accidentally do  `$U = new Utils(); $U->responseText(..)` It's a little thing but it will insure all the methods of this class stay static. It's just a design thing I like to do, on singletons and static classes

**UPDATE** your issue is you are using the `+` to concat in PHP where you should be using the `.`  The `+` is good for Javascript not so much for PHP

And the way you have it with `"` double quotes concat is unnecessary, instead of

```
echo "alert('"+$message+"');\n";
```

Try

```
echo "alert('$message');\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

If i understand you properly bind `javascript` to `php`.

```
<?php
    $script = '<script type="text/javascript">';
    $script .= 'function showAlert(){';
    $script .= 'alert("Hello World.");';
    $script .= '}';
    $script .= '</script>';
    echo $script;
?>
```

Than after page has loaded you can call it !

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        showAlert();
    }
</script>
```